# haskell-dev - Possibly broken

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

**Context:** I'm trying to install the Haskell platform following the steps listed [here](https://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html). Below are the messages I'm seeing in Powershell which don't at all match what I'm seeing [@3:10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLr2u6CjSsM) from individuals who are successfully able to follow the installation steps. Below line seems to imply something with the dependencies is broken...

```
haskell-dev v0.0.1 [Approved] - Possibly broken
```

I see there are instructions for upgrading from the old-style **haskell-platform installer** to the **haskell-dev installer** which I've followed. I think at some point I did install an older version of Haskell on this machine. Following the instructions for upgrading the old-style installer however does not seem to work.

**What I see when running the install instructions:**

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> choco install haskell-dev
Chocolatey v0.10.15
Installing the following packages:
haskell-dev
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading haskell-dev 0.0.1... 100%

haskell-dev v0.0.1 [Approved] - Possibly broken
haskell-dev package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
 The install of haskell-dev was successful.
  Software install location not explicitly set, could be in package or
  default install location if installer.

Chocolatey installed 1/1 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Enjoy using Chocolatey? Explore more amazing features to take your
experience to the next level at
 https://chocolatey.org/compare
PS C:\Windows\system32> ghci
ghci : The term 'ghci' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ghci
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ghci:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

**What others see after successful installation:**
[image]

**Questions:** What am I doing wrong? If I do indeed still have an old distribution of Haskell that I need to uninstall what set of steps do I need to follow to find/uninstall properly -- then reinstall with the newer version via the **haskell-dev** installer? Should I revert to trying to use the older installment method or (as I'm guessing) has that been deprecated for good reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same challenge while installing.

Try:
> choco install haskell-dev --force --force-dependencies

Forcing the dependencies did the trick for me.

With `--force` you won't get an error on an already installed instance.

Don't forget the `> refreshenv` before testing.